# Taking average of certain values in one Excel column based on values in another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a (large) array of data in Excel of which I need to compute the average value of certain values in one column, based on the values of another column. For example, here's a snippet of my data:

[image]

So specifically, I want to take the average of the F635 mean values corresponding with Row values of 1. To take it a step further, I want this to continue to Row values of 2, Row values of 3 etc.

I'm not familiar with how to run code in Excel but have attempted to solve this by using the following:

```
=IF($C = "1", AVERAGE($D:$D), "")
```

which (to my understanding) can be interpreted as "if the values (anywhere) in column C are equal to 1, then take the average of the corresponding values in column D."

Of course, as I try this I get a formula error from Excel.

Any guidance would be incredibly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Excel already has a builtin function for exactly this use; [AVERAGEIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

```
=AVERAGEIF(C:C,1,D:D)
```

Answer (score 0):

For more complicated cases, I would use an array-formula. This one is simple enough for the `AVERAGEIF` formula. For instance `=AVERAGEIF(A1:A23;1;B1:B23)`

Array-formula allows for more elaborate ifs. To replicate the above, you could do `=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$23=1;$B$1:$B$23;0))/COUNT(IF($A$1:$A$23=1;$B$1:$B$23;0))`. 
Looks like more work but you can create extremely elaborate if-statements. Instead of hitting ENTER, do CTRL-ENTER when entering the formula. Use * between criteria to replicate AND or + for OR. Example: `SUM(IF(($A$1:$A$23="apple")*($B$1:$B$23="green");$C$1:$C$23;0))` tallies values for green apples in c1:c23.

Your sample data includes three columns with potential ifs so my guess is that you're going to need array formulas at some point.

Comment: For speed and ease of use one should always use Averageif/s or SUMIF/s instead of Array Formulas.  You are correct that there are times that those will not work and an array formula is needed, Array formulas use a lot of computational iterations where the standard formulas do not.  It is why there is no detriment to full column references in the AVERAGEIF but there is in the array formulas.  Also you can simple bypass the sum/count with this array formula: `AVERAGE(IF(A1:A23=1,B1:B23))`  Every time another reference is made more computations are needed and slows the formula even further.

Comment: Also AVERAGEIFS() will deal with multiple criteria  `AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,"apple",B:B,"green")`